# phpMyAdmin Log In with openshift

Tags: openshift

Since today, I can't log in to phpMyAdmin while until now it was working fine. I'm using root user and root password given when I installed phpMyAdmin. I tried to desinstall and install it again but it didn't change the problem. I have the same problem on another server openShift. Can you help me please? Many thanks.

[Log in failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grvuA.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not login to phpMyAdmin on OpenShift Online as the root user.  If you have lost your username/password for MySQL you can find them again by using one of the following options:

1. SSH into your application using the "`rhc ssh`" command, and then run the command "`env | grep MYSQL`".  This will then show your correct mysql username/password
2. Log into the OpenShift Online web console, view the details for the application and you can view the user/password for the MySQL cartridge
3. Use the "`rhc app show`" command, which will show you the username/password for your MySQL cartridge in it's output.

Comment: That's what I did, It's this username/password I meant when saying Root user and Root password. And it didn't work.

Comment: If you just ssh into your gear and type "mysql" does it connect correctly?

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly, I tried to create a new server on openshift with a mysql and phpmyadmin, and I still can't log in onto it. Could it be a problem from openShift ?

Comment: This should be fixed now, it was a temporary issue with phpmyadmin on openshift online.  You may have to clear your browsers cookies before trying again.